# When using history.push the following screen is not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When changing the screen, using history.push the new screen is not loaded.

I've seen some posts about it, but no solution has actually helped.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Above is my main component, where I use redux

```
const isLogged = localStorage.getItem('user')
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  return isLogged ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className="container-fluid p-0" style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)', }}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
        <AlertComponent />
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Here is my component of routes where I have the login screen and the main screen of my application.

```
const authenticate = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    UserService.login(email, password, (response) => {
      setLoading(false)
      response.error ?
        dispatch(createAlertError('Email e/ou senha inválida'))
        :
        dispatch(userSignInSuccess(response.user.shift()))
      history.push('/')
    })
  }
```

Here in my login component, when calling this function the route changes, but the new component is not updated.

Here is the repository [link](https://github.com/RUANDUARTE03/challenge-reactjs)

Comment: can you specify which files in your repo you're referring to in the question

Comment: I had to add history.go (0) to render the page

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues in your code which you can correct

In your main component don't wrap Provider with `<Router>`, wrap  in `<Provider />`, in that way route handlers can get access to the store. To know more [click](https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router#connecting-react-router-with-redux-app)

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In your `App.js` use `<Router>` and no need to inject history object there, when you're using react router, connected component will have access to it.

Like the `<PrivateRoute>` create one more component as `<PublicRoute>` which will do the exact opposite check of `<PrivateRoute>`

```
const isLogged = localStorage.getItem('user')
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  return isLogged ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className="container-fluid p-0" style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)', }}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <AlertComponent />
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Try above steps and let me know your progress, Thanks

Comment: Previously, my Router included only routes, but in one of the surveys, I suggested covering the entire application.
And referring to the problem, it persists, msm fznd these changes

Answer (score 0):

```
  const authenticate = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    UserService.login(email, password, (response) => {
      setLoading(false)
      response.error ?
        dispatch(createAlertError('Email e/ou senha inválida'))
        :
        dispatch(userSignInSuccess(response.user.shift()), history.push('/'), history.go(0))
    })
  }
```

history.go(0) to render the page again